# NEO4J 4.3.1 json log format not working for http.log

Tags: neo4j

In version 4.3.1 of the common edition, when setting the value dbms. lob. default_format=JSON, the http log is set.json is written as before in the PLAIN format and not in JSON. On debug.the json parameter is distributed.

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure Neo4j ? Testing with a brand new 4.3.1 community shows it is working perfectly fine :

```
$ cat conf/neo4j.conf | grep format
dbms.logs.default_format=json


$ ./bin/neo4j start
Directories in use:
home:         /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1
config:       /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/conf
logs:         /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/logs
plugins:      /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/plugins
import:       /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/import
data:         /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/data
certificates: /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/certificates
licenses:     /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/licenses
run:          /Users/christophewillemsen/dev/_graphs/community-4.3.1/run
Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid:93326). It is available at http://localhost:7474
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.


$ tail -f logs/neo4j.log
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:50:10.777+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:50:10.779+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Started."}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:50:18.061+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:50:18.061+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Stopping..."}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:50:25.835+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Stopped."}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:28.216+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Starting..."}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:30.014+0000","level":"INFO","message":"======== Neo4j 4.3.1 ========"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:31.369+0000","level":"INFO","message":"org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@2b15ba1a"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:31.369+0000","level":"INFO","message":"org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@796fe2b5"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:32.024+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Bolt enabled on localhost:7687."}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:32.605+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/"}
{"time":"2021-08-04 08:51:32.606+0000","level":"INFO","message":"Started."}
```

Comment: problem only with http.log. My settings: dbms.logs.http.enabled=true
dbms.logs.http.rotation.keep_number=5
dbms.logs.http.rotation.size=20m
dbms.logs.gc.enabled=true
dbms.logs.gc.options=-Xlog:gc*,safepoint,age*=trace
dbms.logs.gc.rotation.keep_number=5
dbms.logs.gc.rotation.size=20m
dbms.logs.debug.level=INFO
dbms.logs.default_format=json
dbms.logs.debug.path=debug.jsonl
dbms.logs.http.path=http.jsonl
dbms.logs.debug.rotation.size=20m
dbms.logs.debug.rotation.keep_number=7

Comment: debug. log is formatted perfectly in json. The problem is only with http. log. Perhaps according to the documentation, http. log is not subject to conversion to json